# add color dynamically to added text

Tags: javascript, html

i am working on this example of appendChild() method.but the difference is here i am trying to add more text to a div dynamically.that was all right.but the hard part is the text i want to add will be red in color.how can i do that?
i tried

```
  text.setAttributes('color',"red");
```

But it didn't work.so,how this task can be done??please help,thanks!!!!

the full code is given below............

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function create_text(){
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var text = document.createTextNode(" New text to add.");

    mydiv.appendChild(text);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="create_text();">Create Text Node</button>
<div id="mydiv">Welcome, here is some text.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't apply styles directly to text nodes, and you don't set styles as attributes on elements. They need to go on the `style` object on the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would normally have to use CSS properties, however, text nodes cannot have CSS properties applied to them. You therefore need another container element:

You can choose any container element you wish, e.g. `div`, `span`, etc. It just needs to be capable of containing a text node. Having an element then allows us to access the `styles` property and set various styles (the `color` attribute in your case).

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfRz4/1/)

```
function create_text(){
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");

    var container = document.createElement("span");
    var text = document.createTextNode(" New text to add.");

    container.appendChild(text);
    container.style.color = "red";

    mydiv.appendChild(container);
}
```

---

Further note:

- the order of the color assignments and calls of `appendChild` is arbitrary. The following would also be possible:

  ```
  function create_text(){
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");

    var container = document.createElement("span");
    var text = document.createTextNode(" New text to add.");

    container.appendChild(text);
    mydiv.appendChild(container);

    container.style.color = "red";
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If that's everything in your div, you could try

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.color="#ff0000";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydiv.style.color = 'red';
```

or just in css

```
#mydiv { color: red; }
```

if you have other elements inside the div that you don't want to be red, you'd need to wrap the new text in a span or div or another element before appending.

with jquery this would be super easy:

```
$('#mydiv').append('<span style="color:red">this is new text</span>');
```